# how can I access the window in an exported function?

Tags: angular, openapi-generator

given the module generated by opeapi generator, it expects configuration parameters in particular the baseUrl for API calls.
I need to recover the baseUrl from a configuration object injected into the window.
How can I recover it? I cannot directly access the window because the compiler blocks me.
How can I do?

imported angular module:

```
ApiModule.forRoot(apiConfig)
```

the function:

```
export function apiConfig() {
  return new Configuration({
    basePath: '',
  });
}
```

what i expect is:

```
export function apiConfig () {
   return new Configuration ({
     basePath: 'window.config.baseUrl',
   });
}
```

the solution:

```
function _window(): any {
  return window
}

export function apiConfig() {
  return new Configuration({
    basePath: _window().config,
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean the compiler blocks you?

Comment: the compiler does not recognize window.myObject as valid

Answer (score 0):

You may have to wrap the window object reference and then add it as a provider to use it in your component. See here: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/

Comment: it is a procedure that I have already adopted, but what I ask is how to recover an object that is in the window directly in app.module

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the `window` object below the imports of your file

```
import ....

declare let window: any;

export function apiConfig () {
  return new Configuration ({
      basePath: window.config.baseUrl,
 });
}
```